# Breaking a library into parts and privacy in Dart

Tags: dart, libraries, privacy

I'm trying to break down a library into parts, and having trouble accessing private elements of the library from a part.

For example, say I have a file named stack.dart with the following content:

```
library stack;

final _stack = [];

get isEmpty => _stack.isEmpty;
get top => isEmpty ? throw "Empty stack!" : _stack.last;
get pop => isEmpty ? throw 'Empty stack!' : _stack.removeLast();
push(elt){
  _stack.add(elt);
  return elt;
}
```

I also have another file with the following contents:

```
part of stack;

display(){
  print(_stack); // can't access _stack from here!
}
```

Is this to be expected or am I doing something wrong?

Is `_stack` private to the library or the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you have forgotten to include you file into the library by using the `part` keyword:

lib.dart:

```
library test_lib;
part 'part.dart';

final _private = 'This is private';
```

part.dart:

```
part of test_lib;

void test() {
  print(_private); // I have access to the _private variable defined in lib.dart
}
```

Comment: Also the `Effective Dart` suggests to don't use library names in `part of` directives. https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#do-use-strings-in-part-of-directives